# On what occasions canonical livepatch machine-token change?

Tags: security, canonical-livepatch

On what occasions canonical livepatch machine-token change?

Is it possible to get new livepatch machine-token without fresh installation of OS?

Is it necessary to go through https://ubuntu.com/security/livepatch using any browser?

Comment: Which token are you referring to? Can you [edit] your question to be a bit more complete?

Comment: I have edidted the question.